# Messenger customer chat plugin - referral webhook event not received on mobile

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-customer-chat

I've been using the Messenger customer chat plugin quite often but I recently discovered that I don't receive any 'ref' tags when a mobile user tries to talk to me through the Messenger chat plugin. It does work perfectly whenever someone starts talking on desktop (Chrome, Safari,...)

Is this a known issue and are there any workarounds? I now have no clue where this user came from since I don't receive the referral webhook.

Thanks in advance!